# How to stop or eliminate a function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function that works without any click and it is going on, non stop.

I want to stop that function with a click. In the example, when I click to #blue or #red I do not want that divs visible.

```js
one();
 
function one(){
  $("#blue").fadeOut("2000").delay(2000).fadeIn("2000");
  $("#red").fadeIn("2000").delay(2000).fadeOut("2000");
setTimeout(one, 5000); 
}
 

$("#blue, #red").click(function() {
$("#blue, #red").fadeOut("slow");
$("#green").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
#blue {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px; right:100px;
 width:100px; height:100px;
 background-color: blue;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#red {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px; right:100px;
 width:100px; height:100px;
 background-color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}
 
#green {
 position:absolute;
 top:250px; right:100px;
 width:100px; height:100px;
 background-color: green;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Comment: Assign a variable to your timeout and then clear it. `var x = setTimeout` and then `clearTimeout(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a variable scoped so that it is visible to the onload function as well as the click handler to accomplish this. Check the variable in your function that runs constantly before doing work in the function. Default the variable to true so that the function runs and set it to false upon clicking. See below::

```
var shouldContinue = true;
one();

function one(){
    if(shouldContinue){
        $("#blue").fadeOut("2000").delay(2000).fadeIn("2000");
        $("#red").fadeIn("2000").delay(2000).fadeOut("2000");
        setTimeout(one, 5000); 
    }
}

$("#blue, #red").click(function() {
    shouldContinue = false;
    $("#blue, #red").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#green").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Note if there is a chance that you want to "re-enable" the function and let it continue running at a later time then you can leave the `setTimeout` outside of the if block as follows:

```
function one(){
    if(shouldContinue){
        $("#blue").fadeOut("2000").delay(2000).fadeIn("2000");
        $("#red").fadeIn("2000").delay(2000).fadeOut("2000");
    }
    setTimeout(one, 5000); 
}
```

this will let you set `shouldContinue` to true again after it has been stopped so that the function continues to do work

Comment: Your solution works well. Just to learn, as there is a way to call the function, in this case: one(); Is there any way to "uncall" that function?

Comment: you can't really "uncall" a function but you can perform work in the onclick function for the buttons that sets the state to of the buttons to whatever it was before the `one()` function ever ran (so essentially "uncalling" it but technically that's not what is happening)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stop` method. https://api.jquery.com/stop/

```js
$( "#blue" ).click(function() {
  $( "#blue" ).stop();
});
```

Comment: this will stop the current animation on the element with id `blue`. this will not solve OP's problem (unless I'm misunderstanding the request) as he has a function which runs every 5 seconds. So this answer will stop the animation and then it will happen again in 5 seconds- his request is to permanently kill the function from running as I understand it

Comment: Thx for feedback, colegaues. Will provide working solution later.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use stop() on function itself, that way you dont need to change all code.
Just add -->

```
one().stop();
```

add this after the click listeners and that should do it

Comment: hey it worked.
assign setTimeout to a variable and clear it at the end when we want to stop.

Comment: I think you should provide a full answer. It is not clear to me. 

Inside the aswer panel StackOverflow has an icone to test the code: javascirpt/HTML/CSS Snipped. You can also use other tools to test your code: https://jsbin.com, codepen.io, JSFiddle.net